# How to disable keywords suggestion in phpmyadmin while writing SQL queries in SQL tab?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Want to practice SQL queries, but it provides me with auto-suggestions. I don't want auto suggestions, so I can sharpen my SQL practice perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Personally I find having suggestions _helps_ with learning a system...

Comment: ...why not just use Notepad and copy+paste your query when you're done?

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file (`config.inc.php`), this can be disabled by setting

[$cfg['CodemirrorEnable']](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_CodemirrorEnable) = false;